# Rotating One Bone in All Keyframes of an Animation

Tags: animation

I want to edit a [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/#/) animation in Blender by rotating one bone such that the rotation is applied to all keyframes of the animation.

After loading the animation FBX, this is a screenshot of what I have in the first keyframe:
[image]

This is how I rotated the bone by changing Rotation W value:
[image]

Now I want the rotation to be applied to the bone in every keyframe of the animation. I tried editing the rotation in every keyframe, but as soon as I leave the current keyframe, the rotation changes I made are cancelled. I tried Ctrl-A and applying any of the available options but without success.

How can I rotate to a single bone such that all keyframes of the animation acquire this rotation?

Comment: Have you tried through the Graph Editor? You'll be able to change for the whole line of keyframes. Also it's not normal that the changes you've made are not saved, have you keyframed at least?

Comment: To be honest, I am very new to Blender so I don't know what a Graph Editor is although I know how to access it. Also, I did not understand the phrase "have you keyframed"; the keyframes are there from the imported animation, I did not create any new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same for every keyframe value, you can just first delete the channel by selecting it:

[image]

Then press "X" to delete it.

[image]

Then go back to frame 0.

Enter the value you want to have (in my case the z-rotation)

Then hover over the value and press "I"

[image]

Ready.

Note: I was lazy and did not create bone for you and took another value - but i think you understood the way to go ;)

Comment: Awesome! Cheers :-)

Comment: You are welcome!